# Deployed dotnet core react application, API routes not recognised

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, iis, .net-core

I have a web application .NET core api with a React frontend together as one project which I deployed to my local IIS server. This is a single-page application that makes 2 calls to the API backend. When deployed, none of the API routes are recognised, I checked the Network tab in the developer tools and saw that it was giving me a status code of 304 during the frontend fetch() call.

My IIS version is above version 6. 
I'm not sure where I went wrong. Was it the deployment process where I pushed the project to IIS? Is there something in the Visual Studios settings that I was suppose to do?

Thanks!

Comment: API routes work in local development, but not when deployed.

Comment: Based on my understanding, .net core are supported on IIS 7 or higher version. Since IIS 6 has already retired, I think you should in-place upgrade your OS version. Otherwise, .net core may not work on your side.